# how to use where in cloud firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i am using cloud firestore in firebase functions. i am facing issue with using "where" in the query,since i don't know exact syntax. please correct me, if i am wrong.

```
self.dbManager.collection('test').where('entry_date', '==','2018-06-29').where('entry_status','==','active').get().then( async doc => {
                console.log("doc--------->",doc);
                console.log("doc--------->",doc.data());
                conv.data.userQuesData  =   doc.data()
});
```

i am getting below error, when i use "doc.data()". We have data for the above conditions

```
TypeError: doc.data is not a function
    at MYservice.<anonymous> (/user_code/services/myService.js:99:62)
    at step (/user_code/services/myService.js:32:23)
    at Object.next (/user_code/services/myService.js:13:53)
    at /user_code/services/myService.js:7:71
    at __awaiter (/user_code/services/myService.js:3:12)
    at /user_code/services/daoService.js:94:168
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When performing a query, [get()](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.14.x/Query#get) returns a promise containing a [QuerySnapshot](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.14.x/QuerySnapshot) object.

In your code, you're assigning that QuerySnapshot to a variable called `doc`, then apparently assuming it's a DocumentSnapshot type object, which is a failing.

You need to adjust your code to deal with a QuerySnapshot rather than a DocumentSnapshot.  Please refer to the [QuerySnapshot](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.14.x/QuerySnapshot) docs to understand what comes back from a query against a collection.  In particular, note that the list of document matches that come from a query can be seen in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.14.x/QuerySnapshot#docs) property as [QueryDocumentSnapshot](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.14.x/QueryDocumentSnapshot.html) objects.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute a query against a collection, there can be multiple documents that match the conditions. For that reason the query returns a `QuerySnapshot`, which contains the matching documents. You will need to loop over the `QuerySnapshot` to get the individual documents:

```
self.dbManager.collection('test').where('entry_date', '==','2018-06-29').where('entry_status','==','active').get().then( async querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        console.log("doc--------->",doc.data());
    });
});
```

Note that this is pretty well covered in the [documentation on getting multiple documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection), which I recommend since the query functionality builds on top of that.